# Build failing in CI using Jenkins

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have been trying to do CI using Jenkins. I configured the Jenkins server, and started building my application from it. According to the log, cloning the remote is successful, cleaning is complete however build fails with the following warning:

```
The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/qbuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ebztfecuuuccclffxpsgkoaacypt/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Release-iphoneos/MyAppTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyAppTests normal arm64
```

Can someone help me out from here.

Comment: For CI, I have used OS X and XCode server. Its pretty easy, why don't you try that? Here is the link if you want: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH1-SW1

Comment: Thank you but this was requirement

Comment: @Kaey we'll need more logs to see what causes the problem, usually the best is if you search for "error:" and for "warning:" in the Xcode logs as noted on our DevCenter: http://devcenter.bitrise.io/docs/frequent-ios-issues.html#searching-for-errors-and-issues-in-xcode-generated-outputs (you can find **grep** examples as well there)